# Destroying a spammer summoned lolcat

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

I just destroyed a SPAM account, which summoned a lolcat. The usual output of the process did not appear, just the exception handler.

The account was successfully destroyed, however.

I am noting it just in case it's not one of those five minute things. Since my IP address is banned unless I'm logged in, I'm unable to create additional (unregistered) accounts to try and reproduce it.

Comment: For some reason I read the title as if you were engaged in an epic battle with an lolcat summoned by a spammer trying to avoid Diamond Justice™

Comment: @TimStone I was half tempted _not_ to fix the title, but I did.

Comment: Why does the title *still* read like it comes from http://gaming.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Would it help if I edit the question to say "I just destroyed a SPAM account **with my power glove**" ?

Comment: I'm not saying that it's a *bad* thing ;-)

Comment: @JoachimSauer The power glove, the title, or both? :P

Comment: lolcat.. the Excalibur of spammers! :D

Comment: *Since my IP is banned unless I'm logged in* wat

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ Yes, my IP is banned from asking or (I believe) answering questions unless registered (I get the generic go away message).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Someone else deleted the same user at *exactly* the same time, I'll add a quick plain-text output for this uber-rare race case.

Comment: Ahhh, yes .. Egon _said_ to never cross the streams.

Comment: Just curious.. do you (Nick) have access to data that Tim can't access? Or is it just experience talking? :)

Comment: @Shadow Tim is 'just' a mod. Nick's a dev.

Comment: Thanks @Pekka and Aakash.. should have looked in their profile! ;)

Comment: @Shadow - yes, we have access to...well, everything (in this case the error log...every time you see a lolcat, we log it)

Comment: Aren't you using transactions in the database, though? How could this cause a race condition?

Comment: @George - Mod 1 and 2 both open the mod menu, one hits the destroy button, the next hits it after the user is gone...when the second mod tries he's attempting to destroy a user that no longer exists, which we (correctly) throw an error on.  I simply added a check for *just* this which throws a readable message back to the mod saying what's happened.

Comment: @Nick: Ah, that makes sense.