# This post has now been deleted

Tags: discussion, flags, deleted-answers

I was flagging an answer as not an answer, and I got the message "This post has now been deleted".

Wowee! Did my flag, like, **totally** nuke the answer? Or was it something that happened independently of my flagging? If so, would "This post has since been deleted" be less confusing?

**Edit:** [Nothing known about.... when trying ri String#upcase Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625631/nothing-known-about-when-trying-ri-stringupcase-ruby/8484205#8484205) should link to the deleted answer.

Comment: Link, please (to the question, or the deleted answer if you still have the URL).

Comment: Another possibility is that the answer had already been flagged and someone acted on that flag while you were adding yours.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Strong possibilty, considering it was you who deleted it :)

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Yeah, that worked out funnier than I'd imagined. I posted my comment before the link went up. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That happens from time to time. You probably just flagged shortly after a post was deleted, presumably while a moderator was working through the queue, or after several high reputation users cast delete votes.

I can't find the exact transcripts, but this same behavior has been mentioned in chat several times. Moderators sometimes see the reverse of this, we go to take action on something in the queue only to realize that it's no longer there. Sometimes, strange things happen when we [cross the proverbial streams](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108421/destroying-a-spammer-summoned-lolcat).

There are times when your flag will tip a threshold for Community to automatically remove something (typical for comments), but you don't receive a notification that the post had already been deleted when that happens.