# Clicking on the "accept answer" check mark is not a vote

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, deleted-answers, wording, error-message

Clicking on the "accept answer" check mark is not a vote from the user's standpoint, but this error message says so:

[image: screenshot of the banner]

> This post has been deleted; deleted posts can't be voted on

I would like to change this to something less confusing for those not familiar with the internal mechanism behind the curtain.

Comment: Internally, accepting is considered a vote. Several other things, such as bounty awards, are also considered votes. (Confusingly, some "votes", such as close/reopen votes, are actually instead considered *flags* internally.)

Comment: OK, but what you suggest instead? There's not much to discuss. Better make this into feature request, suggesting a new wording in such case.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard done. Suggestions are better placed in answers so that one can vote on them. E.g. "Deleted answers cannot be marked as accepted.".I don't mind much, just found the message ameliorable.

Comment: Also deleted posts can be voted on given that undelete is a vote.

Comment: Maybe we should just fix all such error messages. This has been causing confusion for a while now and it leaks implementation details.

Answer (score 6):

I'll add a rewording suggestion:

> Deleted answers cannot be marked as accepted.

Comment: I think that same message is currently shown if you try to upvote or downvote the post. Of course presumably some extra code could distinguish these conditions but the simplest answer would be to have text that works for everything I guess.

Comment: @RobertLongson that'd work too

Comment: We could use a wording similar to: [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115815/282094) or [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294912/282094) for consistency, see: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u4qf.png). That would **also** explain the situation where the post is deleted (out from under you) and the user isn't made aware of that yet. Not the perfect message, but a consistent one; what you are trying to do doesn't work on deleted posts.