# Destroying a spammer summoned a lolcat (again)

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

I just destroyed a spam / robot account that was just copying the help text into answers and posting them. The ID was 2045498.

Upon hitting 'destroy', I got the lolcat exception page. I loaded the user's profile again (following a link from one of the junk answers, not refreshing) and this is what I saw:

- The name had been de-normalized
- No traces of the 5 spam answers that previously existed
- No bio data at all

However the account still existed. Destroying it *again* worked. Bug, or perhaps something related to the testing / maintenance that's going on? It's almost like a transaction failed.

Noting it here in case it's the prior.

Comment: As for 'again', this [seems to now be a pattern](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108421/destroying-a-spammer-summoned-lolcat?rq=1) for me.

Comment: There has been other odd behavior around the spam flags lately, so you're not the only one here.